# Prevent that when an app is assigned to All desktops, then while switching spaces it becomes visible during space switch scrolling

Tags: trackpad, spaces, macos, multi-touch

When I set an app to be available on all spaces

[image]

Then while while scrolling to another Space using the 3/4 finger swipe gesture the Apps are visible until I completely switch to the space and than they disappear.

This annoying and makes no sense. How do I stop this behavior/bug?

[image]